# Xcode 6 Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Thanks

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, linker

Can someone please help me with this error? linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here is the text with the error:

```
Ld /Users/Wendy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenButt-bmsbdabratidppbftwocobuuxllt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChickenButtTests.xctest/ChickenButtTests normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/Wendy/Desktop/Sound A Plenty"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/Wendy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenButt-bmsbdabratidppbftwocobuuxllt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Wendy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenButt-bmsbdabratidppbftwocobuuxllt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/Wendy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenButt-bmsbdabratidppbftwocobuuxllt/Build/Intermediates/ChickenButt.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChickenButtTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ChickenButtTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -bundle_loader /Users/Wendy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenButt-bmsbdabratidppbftwocobuuxllt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sound\ A\ Plenty.app/Sound\ A\ Plenty -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework XCTest -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Wendy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenButt-bmsbdabratidppbftwocobuuxllt/Build/Intermediates/ChickenButt.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChickenButtTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ChickenButtTests.swiftmodule -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Wendy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenButt-bmsbdabratidppbftwocobuuxllt/Build/Intermediates/ChickenButt.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChickenButtTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ChickenButtTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Wendy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenButt-bmsbdabratidppbftwocobuuxllt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChickenButtTests.xctest/ChickenButtTests

ld: file not found: /Users/Wendy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenButt-bmsbdabratidppbftwocobuuxllt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sound A Plenty.app/Sound A Plenty
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As well as a photo here: http://tinypic.com/view.phppic=2aaj28w&s=8#.VZ6sXe1Viko

I think I got this error from changing my icon image.

Comment: Did you ever sort this I am having the same problem now?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answer is in this line:

```
ld: file not found: /Users/Wendy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenButt-bmsbdabratidppbftwocobuuxllt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sound A Plenty.app/Sound A Plenty
```

When you changed your icon image did you change the name of it perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. Just go to **Enable Bitcode** in Build Setting, and change it to **No**

Credit to:
[New warnings in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios9)