# Xcode7: libGGLAnalytics.a(GGLContext+Analytics.o)' does not contain bitcode

Tags: ios, xcode7, bitcode

Using Xcode7. When I run my app on the simulator I get no errors. When I try to run on a real device I get this:

```
ld: 'Test-IOS/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLAnalytics.a(GGLContext+Analytics.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**How do I resolve this error?**

Comment: getting the same error... had any luck ?

Comment: This has the same cause as [Google Analytics libAdIdAccess.a does not contain bitcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395260/google-analytics-libadidaccess-a-does-not-contain-bitcode)

Answer (score 24):

The issue is that Google Analytics for iOS doesn't have support for bitcode right now. Here's the issue on Google Code:

https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=671

The workaround currently is to disable bitcode for your project.
In your project file in the `Build Settings` tab under `Build Options` set the `Enable Bitcode` flag to false.

[image: Bitcode Flag]

Note that if you disable it completely you won't be able to build for watchOS. There seems to be a way to also only disable it for iOS but then you won't be able to use analytics on watchOS.

Comment: It seems like Google fixed the issue, but has not released it via CocoaPods yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved by Google. If you follow the Google Issue further down (https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=671), you'll see the solution is to update to Google Analytics 3.14 SDK which includes bitcode support.

If you use CocoaPods, note the pod name is a little unintuitive. If you ONLY use Google Analytics, you'll want:

pod 'GoogleAnalytics'

NOT -> pod 'Google/Analytics'

If you use more than Analytics, you will need the second entry BUT I believe there might still not be Bitcode support for the "Google/Analytics" library.

I can confirm though, that if you only need Analytics, the above does work. I'm on Xcode 7.2, BTW.

Comment: when i change it to `pod 'GoogleAnalytics'` it show's an error missing file on line `#import <Google/Analytics.h>` which file do i have to import to get access

Comment: Hi, In my own project, I after using the pod 'GoogleAnalytics', I am using #import <GAI.h> and #import <GAIDictionaryBuilder.h>

Comment: Thnx, didn't work on mine it said `GGLContext` doesn't exist