# iOS 9 (Xcode 7) Facebook API/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKAccessToken.o)' does not contain bitcode

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, ios9, bitcode

I am trying to build the my app containing Facebook SDK with Xcode 7 in iOS 9.0. I am getting this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your Facebook SDK version to 4.6

> The SDK supports various iOS 9 features including Bitcode. In
>   addition, the SDK dialogs such as Login, Like, Share Dialogs
>   automatically determine the best UI based on the device, including
>   SFSafariViewController instead of Safari. Follow the our Preparing for
>   iOS 9 guide.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads

Facebook SDK 4.6 [Download Link](https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910.zip)

Also check this for upgrading to iOS 9 Facebook SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

---

If you getting another bitcode error from other SDK then you can disable bitcode from setting of Xcode target.

For Bitcode issue you can check this question : [New warnings in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios9)

If you have all SDK (Frameworks) with the bitcode enabled then you will not get the bitcode error. If you get that error then Disable it from settings.

[image]

Comment: I downloaded this crap (version 4.28) today, and it did not have bitcode. Fail.

Comment: [4.28.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads) is the latest version as of today (20171116). It really does not include bitcode for some of the bundled sub-frameworks. However I think I was able to fix my issue by installing the SDK through cocoapods, which really means it compiles it all from scratch, thus getting bitcode enabled. For anyone with the same problem, check out https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git

Comment: That's good. The code you linked to are all precomiled binaries with no bitcode in them. Also https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started does not mention Cocoapods anywhere, I had to google around for awhile to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm just gonna add my own answer.

Import using Cocoapods.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git

That will get bitcode compiled into the framework.