# Xcode / mod_pbxproj: How to set ENABLE_BITCODE

Tags: python, xcode, unity-game-engine, bitcode, unity3d-editor

I am trying to modify a Unity3D generated Xcode project with [mod_pbxproj.py](https://github.com/kronenthaler/mod-pbxproj) called from a python script which is triggered by a [PostProcessBuild](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Callbacks.PostProcessBuildAttribute.html) attribute. I need to set *ENABLE_BITCODE = NO* due to the problem described in [New warnings in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios9).

I am a Python newbie and don't know much about the Xcode PBX internals. I tried a number of calls like

```
    project.add_flags ('ENABLE_BITCODE=NO')
```

or array, dictionary, etc. variants. Everything I tried either did not do the job or threw an error in the system logs. Finally I ended up with a patch in mod_pbxproj.py which does what I want:

```
def add_other_buildsetting(self, flag, value):
    build_configs = [b for b in self.objects.values() if b.get('isa') == 'XCBuildConfiguration']
    for b in build_configs:
        if b.add_other_buildsetting(flag, value):
            self.modified = True
```

and

```
def add_other_buildsetting(self, flag, value):
    modified = False
    base = 'buildSettings'
    key = flag

    if not self.has_key(base):
        self[base] = PBXDict()
    self[base][key] = value                             
    modified = True
    return modified
```

Now calling `project.add_other_buildsetting ('ENABLE_BITCODE', 'NO')` works almost as expected. I got 5 entries in the pbxproj file instead of the 2 changes I noticed when setting the option manually in Xcode. Anyway it seems to work so far.

**But:** Patching a well known piece of software feels pretty strange and I cannot believe that it is not possible to add (or modify) an option in the root of the *buildSettings* tree using the standard mod_pbxproj.py.

How can this be achieved?

**Edit:** [My fork](https://github.com/kayy/mod-pbxproj) of mod_pbxproj

Comment: I couldn't figure this out either. Thanks for the patch, seems to be working perfectly so far.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have latest `mod_pbxproj.py` this works fine:

```
project.add_flags({'ENABLE_BITCODE':'NO'})
```

You can get mod_pbxproj.py from here: https://github.com/kronenthaler/mod-pbxproj/blob/master/mod_pbxproj/mod_pbxproj.py