# import built error shows in test flight when upload and when make an ipa it shows error in export myapp.ipa.?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode7, testflight

When i upload my app to TestFlight it shows import built error and when i tried to make an ipa it shows error in exporting ipa. I tried so many times but same error comes. How to solve this issue.please help me. Below there is a screenshot regarding error comes during ipa creation process.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpa7a.png)

Comment: Try to disable the bitcode option. Check @stevechen answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios-9?lq=1

Comment: thanx for your comment..problem solved..but i need to know why showing error when i upload using bitcode..what is the use of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution** Disable the "Bitcode" option. How to do it? Check out @stevechen answer [New warnings in ios 9](http://wwww.stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios-9?lq=1)

**What's the "Bitcode"?** Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a new version of your app to the store.