# I got error when archive my app after add googelADS by Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

I added Google ads GoogleMobileAds.framework, but when I do archive to my app to upload it to App Store, I got this error. What is the problem?

> ld: '/Users/Admin/Desktop/osama/mohmed22/mohmed/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADInterstitial.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @brian , This issue is already answered here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30856364/1730345

Comment: @karthik I'm not the one who asked this question. The user on the right, in the blue box, is the author.

Comment: @Brian , Sorry about that.

Comment: @karthik No problem. Also, the author gets notified any time a comment is made on his post, so he should see your comment even though you tagged me.