# Xcode 7.2/Unity Linker command error exit code 1

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcode7, ipad-2

im trying to build a unity and then send it to my ipad .The build works fine but when xcode wants to send the app to my ipad I get this error :

```
"ld: '/Users/SygnusUser1/Documents/anomproject/Assets/U3DXT/Editor/lib/libU3DXTCoreExtras.a(UP_ALAssetRepresentation.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
```

Im using xcode 7.2 and unity 5.3.3 . Any ideas on why this might be happening?

EDIT

Screenshot of log , app shows black screen and then closes.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New warnings in iOS 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios-9)

Comment: @Rana thank you, that solved my problem . I now have another problem , I launch the game and a black screen shows up and then the game closes.Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Yes ==== 
2016-03-11 15:14:56.363 sliceandrise[646:149838] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist. @Rana

Comment: I have updated my post with a screenshot of the log @Rana

Answer (score 0):

You may need to turn off Remote Notifications

1. In the Project Navigator click the project
2. In the Projects and Targets list click the target.
3. Click Capabilities
4. Expand and turn on Background Modes
5. Click and Turn off Remote Notifications