# Need assistance with RESTKit - BitCode and Duplicate Symbols in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, bitcode, duplicate-symbol

Edited: Removed initial extraneous information that was unrelated.

I have 'inherited' an Objective C project that includes two separate libraries.  There are a set of dependencies that is causing errors of symbol duplication, with samples shown below.

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_RKManagedObjectSeeder in:
>       libs for device/libs/RESTKit/Debug-iphoneos/libRestKitCoreData.a(RKManagedObjectSeeder.o)
>       libs/WebServiceLibrary/libWebServiceLibrary.a(RKManagedObjectSeeder.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_RKManagedObjectSeeder._delegate in:
>       libs for device/libs/RESTKit/Debug-iphoneos/libRestKitCoreData.a(RKManagedObjectSeeder.o)
>       libs/WebServiceLibrary/libWebServiceLibrary.a(RKManagedObjectSeeder.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_RKManagedObjectSeeder._manager in:
>       libs for device/libs/RESTKit/Debug-iphoneos/libRestKitCoreData.a(RKManagedObjectSeeder.o)
>       libs/WebServiceLibrary/libWebServiceLibrary.a(RKManagedObjectSeeder.o)

This is the RESTKit Project target that had bitcode disabled, same with the singular main target of the base project using RESTKit.

These errors appeared after solving a bitcode issue by setting ENABLE_BITCODE to ’No’ as suggested here: [New warnings in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios-9)
I think that this is unreleated, but I leave it here in case there is some correlation

… And about 200 more errors of identical nature.

The setup is like this:

- Main project - Includes both RESTKit and WebServices libraries.
- WebServices project includes RESTKit
- RESTKit project is built separately and included and referenced in BOTH main project like already stated, but it's a separate library.

I know the project was working at some time because the app is on the app store, but sparse comments and a lot of code are making it difficult to see how it ever did.