# Xcode Swift 2 Weather App problems

Tags: ios, xcode, api, swift2, xcode7

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var cityNameTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var cityNameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var cityTempLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func getDataButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    getWeatherData("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(cityNameTextField.text)&APPID=6de03a1d1554874e7594a89fad719dd0")
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getWeatherData("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=6de03a1d1554874e7594a89fad719dd0")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.    
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.        
}

func getWeatherData(urlString: String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.setLabels(data!)
        })   
    }
    task.resume()        
}


 var jsonData: AnyObject?

func setLabels(weatherData: NSData) {


    do {

        self.jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options: []) as! NSDictionary

    } catch {
        //error handle here

    }

    if let name = jsonData!["name"] as? String {

        cityTempLabel.text = "\(name)"

    }



    if let main = jsonData!["main"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let temp = main["temp"] as? Double {
            cityTempLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", temp)
        }
    }
}

};
```

Yesterday I had the app running and this morning I've just been getting new error messages that won't even allow the code to be compiled. They say 'Missing "Default-568h@2x.png" launch image' and 'Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftcode'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Comment: Try cleaning your project. Also, did you check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios-9

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something to your info.plist file:

[image]

It's because the URL link you're trying to get data from is not a secured link, so adding this to you `info.plist` allows you to access that link. Just go to you `info.plist` and right-click and select Add Row, then add exactly what you see in the image above.

Also, remove the `getWeatherData` function from the `viewDidLoad` method, as you don't need that, as you call it when you press your button.

Also, I've noticed one of your labels isn't set correctly in your `setLabels` function, as they both try to set the `cityTempLabel` label, so update the other one to be `cityNameLabel`.

Build and run and it should all work.